# In Wiki Server 4 on OS X Server the first page includes four images that link to other pages. How do i add more?

Tags: osx-server, server.app

In Wiki Server 4 on OS X Server the first page includes four images that link to other pages. How do i add more?

You can click on them to go to another place in wiki server. How do i create more images that link to URLs? I know how to create text links to URLs... but i can't seem to be able to add more images just like the ones on the first page.

Anyone?

Comment: Do you not understand HTML and how to edit the templates or are you instead looking for the locations of the files to edit them? (or are you just asking if the wiki can self-edit itself and directions to do that?)

Comment: Apple's interface does not allow, as far as i can tell URLs behind images. An image is treated as a piece of content that can be viewed and downloaded... not as a way to create buttons and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can...

Upload any image using the Add image (not the attachment) button in edit mode.
Once uploaded. While still in edit mode. Click on the same line right "before" the image, not on the image itself... in the white space.

A new button will appear in the edit toolbar at the top it will say Link (down arrow).

Click that... it works just like normal links, and you can link that photo anywhere.

Click Save... now when you click the image... instead of getting another window with the preview... you get redirected to the URL you provided.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple Server v5.x (OSX El Capitan), in order to use a url link on an uploaded image, click the paperclip to attach the image.  Once attached, there will be a new button that appears at the top of the page called 'Link'. Select it to link to a local page or other URL.  You can only perform this function after attaching, but before saving the changes.  If you save accidentally, you'll need to delete the image and re-attach to perform the link.